# É possível tratar o recebimento de dados em camel casing usando OData?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, asp.net-web-api-2

No método `Register` da classe **`WebApiConfig`** eu tenho configurado um **`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{           
    //Resto do código removido para brevidade
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
}
```

Isso faz com que os dados recebidos (ou enviados) por JSON, sejam convertidos de `camelCase` (padrão do client - JavaScript) para `TitleCase` (padrão que uso nas propriedades no server) e vice-versa.

Ex. de JSON que a API recebe num método **`PATCH`** **normal** (sem usar o **`Delta<T>`**)

```js
{
    id: 1,
    nome: "Joaquim",
    idade: 150
}
```

Isso é "traduzido" para

```js
{
    Id: 1,
    Nome: "Joaquim",
    Idade: 150
}
```

Até aí tudo bem, o problema é que eu tenho uma `action` **`PATCH`** em um `ApiController` que faz uso do [`Delta<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.delta.aspx) e as requisições que são enviadas para este método acabam não passando por esta "tradução".

Eu li em alguns lugares que o OData usa um serializador e um deserializador próprio e este deve ser o problema.

Método **`PATCH`** do `ApiController`:

```
[HttpPatch, ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch(int id, [FromBody] Delta<Entity> changes)
{
    var entity = await _db.Entities.FindAsync(id);
    if (entity == null)        
        return NotFound();

    changes.Patch(entity);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Existe alguma forma de tratar o "*casing*" dos dados recebidos em **`actions`** que usam OData?

Eu vou precisar escrever um novo serializador ou já tem algo pronto que possa me ajudar com isso? Se for necessário escrever um serializador, é possível me ajudar com pelo menos a implementação básica do mesmo?

**Exemplo do JSON que recebo no método com `Delta<T>`**

```
{ nome: "Teste método PATCH" }
```

Se eu enviar o JSON, como o abaixo, funciona normal.

```js
{ Nome: "Teste método PATCH" }
```

---

Obs.: Estou usando OWIN, mas a aplicação está sendo hospedada no IIS (usando o pacote (**`Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`**).

Comment: Tem um site com samples do ASP.NET que tem [um projeto para tratar a serialização do `Delta<T>`](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/DeltaJsonDeserialization/ReadMe.txt). Talvez te ajude.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que isso irá resolver o problema:

Aplique este atributo [CamelCasingFilter] a qualquer action que você queira como camel casing.

```
public class CamelCasingFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private JsonMediaTypeFormatter _camelCasingFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();

    public CamelCasingFilterAttribute()
    {
        _camelCasingFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        ObjectContent content = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content as ObjectContent;
        if (content != null)
        {
            if (content.Formatter is JsonMediaTypeFormatter)
            {
                actionExecutedContext.Response.Content = new ObjectContent(content.ObjectType, content.Value, _camelCasingFormatter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528779/use-camel-case-serialization-only-for-specific-actions?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar o método de extensão EnableLowerCamelCase:

```
Using System.Web.OData.Builder;
Using System.Web.OData.Extensions;

Var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder ();
Builder.EnableLowerCamelCase ();
```

Veja tambem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn746676%28v=vs.118%29.aspx.

Comment: Isso não funciona porque o `builder` é usado para serializar objetos e meu objetivo é deserializar um payload.